# How to dynamicaly navigate/find element to trigger another element jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a input field and when it updates i want to another one to show up.
In this case its simple, but if i have 100 html rows like this, i can't rely on the simple version, example below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Test</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control test" name="test">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Test2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control test2" name="test">
    </div>
</div>

Simple example: 

$('.test2').fadeIn(500);
```

Instead of this i need a more dynamic solution, this is just how i imagine it would be, but a working example is appreciated.

```
<script>
   $('.test2').hide();

     if($('.test')).change(function(){
        $(this).prev('div').closest('.test2').fadeIn(500);
     });
</script>
```

Comment: There's no `.test2` element in your page? Also, you should use the `change()` method to attach an event. It doesn't return a boolean you can hook to

Comment: added the test2 class, seams i manage to delite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding test2 class to your second input, this works this way

```js
$('.test2').closest("div").hide();
$('.test').change(function() {
  $(".test2", $(this).closest('.row')).closest("div").fadeIn(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Test</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control test" name="test">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Test2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control test2" name="test">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Test</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control test" name="test">
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-6 hide">
    <label>Test2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="test_2">
 </div>
</div>
```

And

```
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[name=test]').change(function(){
             $(this).closest('div.row').find('div').eq(2).fadeIn(500);
        });
     });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to hide `test2` div containers using `collapse` class, so it will be hidden by default instead of hide it using the js method `hide()` what will hide the elements after the DOM is ready so the user will notice the disappearing of inputs  :

```
<div class="col-md-6 collapse">
  <label>Test2</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control test2" name="test">
</div>
```

**NOTE :** `collapse` class set the element display to `none`.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.test').on('input', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').find(".test2").closest("div").fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Test</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control test" name="test">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 collapse">
    <label>Test2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control test2" name="test">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this suggestion.